# Is my question still too broad?

Tags: discussion, too-broad

In [Room search, housemates, setting boundaries early](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/7808/room-search-housemates-setting-boundaries-early), I asked how to set some important boundaries early on during a moving process.

The question is when. 5 hours ago, the question was voted as too broad. I've since made some refinements.

Can you explain whether my question is still too broad, and why?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but I've just read your current version and it still feels like an odd fit for the site. Are you looking for feedback and validation on your chosen method of sorting roommates? Are you asking how people would usually do that sort of thing?

> Am I doing this right?

Isn't really a great format for SE, because it lends itself to rather opinion based yes/no answers rather than more focused-longer answers backed by research or experience.

Asking us to help you word an advert probably isn't going to go well either.

**It may be better to be specific about what sort of boundaries you're looking to set and ask people about how to explain these boundaries to potential roommates in an interview process.**

Comment: Thanks for the input. You're right about the broadness. I was trying to be more specific, but instead I added my own answer. I've updated the question now.